# Build matrix with applied formula in R

Tags: r, matrix, datatable

i have problem with implementing a formula inside the matrix from data table.
for example i have this data table

```
Lines <- "vars val1  val2
m     2    1
n     3    1
o     4    2"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)

vars val1  val2
 m     2    1
 n     3    1
 o     4    2
```

and i want to implement the formula in the matrix such as (m1-m2)+(m1-m2),(m1-m2)+(n1-n2),(m1-m2)+(o1-o2), and so on.
So, the matrix would be like this

```
       m           n           o 
m (2-1)+(2-1) (2-1)+(3-1) (2-1)+(4-2)
n (3-1)+(2-1) (3-1)+(3-1) (3-1)+(4-2)
o (4-2)+(2-1) (4-2)+(3-1) (4-2)+(4-2)
```

and the final result would be

```
    m  n  o
 m  2  3  3
 n  3  4  4
 o  3  4  4
```

can it be done with using dcast function ?
if not then, any solution would be accepted.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not clear exactly what you have or precisely what form you want since the question variously refers to a data.table and matrix and the input and output are not shown reproducibly (which is a requirement for posting questions -- see info at the top of the [r](/questions/tagged/r) tag page); however, assuming that the input is the data frame `DF` shown reproducibly in the Note at the end, take the difference of the two val* columns and add the names giving the named vector `dif` and then take the outer sum shown:

```
dif <- with(DF, setNames(val1 - val2, vars))
outer(dif, dif, "+")
```

giving this matrix (convert to whatever form you want if you did not want a matrix):

```
  m n o
m 2 3 3
n 3 4 4
o 3 4 4
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "vars val1  val2
 m     2    1
 n     3    1
 o     4    2"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. thats exactly what im looking for.. 
sorry about my question which is not really clear.. im trying to edit it..

Comment: sorry sir, could i ask again? what if i have another formula like this [link](https://imgur.com/ffDE7Ej) ? i have tried using function inside outer such as `function(a,b){((a+a)+(b+b))}` where a = DF$val1 and b=DF$val2 but the result matrix is incorrect like this [link](https://imgur.com/Xo8iwTM)

Comment: Change the minus to a plus in the definition of `dif``.

Comment: sorry but it wont change the sequence of calculation bcs this is different sequence unlike before.. i mean the formula would be like **(val1 in row1 + val1 in row1) + (val2 in row1 + val2 in row1), (val1 in row1 + val1 in row2) + (val1 in row1 + val1 in row2)**, and so on.. this is the full matrix formula [link](https://imgur.com/ffDE7Ej)

Comment: Your link shows an output with reverse diagonals of 6, c(7, 7), c(9, 8, 9),
c(10, 10), 12 and that is what you get if you replace - with + .

Comment: ooh.. i just recognize.. i thought that the sequence would be similar and only the operator would change. But, it creates different sequence which is a reverse diagonal from the previous form.. thank you so much..
so if the operator is minus but with the same reverse diagonal, is that possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [@G. Grothendieck's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65737298/12158757), we can use `outer` + `dimnames<-`

```
with(
  df,
  `dimnames<-`(outer(val1 - val2, val1 - val2, "+"), rep(list(vars), 2))
)
```

which gives

```
  m n o
m 2 3 3
n 3 4 4
o 3 4 4
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(vars = c("m", "n", "o"), val1 = 2:4, val2 = c(1L, 
1L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```